# Converting date from Jquery date selector for Rails controller?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My Jquery date selector is passing my date variable in the format "22+Mar+2012" but my controller method is looking for YYYY-MM-DD. How would I go about converting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you?

> Date.parse("22+Mar+2012").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
>
> => "2012-03-22"

Comment: Beautiful! To accept the variable I just changed to: Date.parse("#{params[:end_date]}").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

Comment: You don't even need to put the params hash inside of a string. Date.parse(params[:end_date]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")